# Angular Owl Date Time Picker Labels and Buttons not localized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

In the Owl Date Time Picker, the From and To labels, as well as Set and Cancel buttons are not localized. My code for specifying the locale is:

```
constructor(
  private dateTimeAdapter: DateTimeAdapter<any>
) {
    dateTimeAdapter.setLocale(localStorage.getItem('localeId'));
}
```

Tried with de, fr, zh

[image]

"ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0"

What could be the issue?

Edit:

To test, I tried:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SampleTableComponent } from './sample-table/sample-table.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { MatFormComponent } from './mat-form/mat-form.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
  cancelBtnLabel: 'C';
  setBtnLabel: 'S';
  rangeFromLabel: 'F';
  rangeToLabel: 'T';
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SampleTableComponent,
    MatFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But I'm still seeing From, To, Set, Cancel

Comment: In your case the labels and messages seem to be not localized - try the approach in my answer below and adjust the strings to your needs (I believe Chineese but please correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Localization for different languages and formats is defined by `OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE` and `OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS`. Here's the [official doc](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats).

Setting the locale:

By default, the OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE injection token will use the existing LOCALE_ID locale code from @angular/core. If you want to override it, you can provide a new value for the OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE token:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    // use french locale
    {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr'},
  ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

It's also possible to set the locale at runtime using the setLocale() method of the DateTimeAdapter.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTimeAdapter } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: 'app-example.html',
})
export class AppExample {
    constructor(dateTimeAdapter: DateTimeAdapter<any>) {
        dateAdapter.setLocale('ja-JP'); // change locale to Japanese
    }
}
```

In these examples french and japaneese are used - in your case it would be `zh`

In your case the labels and messages seem to be not localized - try the following and adjust the strings to your needs (I believe Chineese but please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OwlDateTimeIntl} from 'ng-pick-datetime';

// here is the default text string - just adjust the strings to reflect your preferred language
export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl = {
    /** A label for the up second button (used by screen readers).  */
    upSecondLabel= 'Add a second',

    /** A label for the down second button (used by screen readers).  */
    downSecondLabel= 'Minus a second',

    /** A label for the up minute button (used by screen readers).  */
    upMinuteLabel= 'Add a minute',

    /** A label for the down minute button (used by screen readers).  */
    downMinuteLabel= 'Minus a minute',

    /** A label for the up hour button (used by screen readers).  */
    upHourLabel= 'Add a hour',

    /** A label for the down hour button (used by screen readers).  */
    downHourLabel= 'Minus a hour',

    /** A label for the previous month button (used by screen readers). */
    prevMonthLabel= 'Previous month',

    /** A label for the next month button (used by screen readers). */
    nextMonthLabel= 'Next month',

    /** A label for the previous year button (used by screen readers). */
    prevYearLabel= 'Previous year',

    /** A label for the next year button (used by screen readers). */
    nextYearLabel= 'Next year',

    /** A label for the previous multi-year button (used by screen readers). */
    prevMultiYearLabel= 'Previous 21 years',

    /** A label for the next multi-year button (used by screen readers). */
    nextMultiYearLabel= 'Next 21 years',

    /** A label for the 'switch to month view' button (used by screen readers). */
    switchToMonthViewLabel= 'Change to month view',

    /** A label for the 'switch to year view' button (used by screen readers). */
    switchToMultiYearViewLabel= 'Choose month and year',

    /** A label for the cancel button */
    cancelBtnLabel= 'Cancel',

    /** A label for the set button */
    setBtnLabel= 'Set',

    /** A label for the range 'from' in picker info */
    rangeFromLabel= 'From',

    /** A label for the range 'to' in picker info */
    rangeToLabel= 'To',

    /** A label for the hour12 button (AM) */
    hour12AMLabel= 'AM',

    /** A label for the hour12 button (PM) */
    hour12PMLabel= 'PM',
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl},
    ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

Source: Official-docs

Comment: Does this have to be done for every language? Our application supports 10 languages

Comment: @user5155835 Yes - but in order to save you some troubles you could map the values with a i18n-lib in json-format for those 20 labels..

Comment: Do you want the component's module ts file or app.module.ts file? Where should the above be put?

Comment: the component ts should suffice

Comment: I've updated the question with module ts file. Do you find any issues in it?

Comment: Did you get to see it?

Answer (score 0):

ok, none worked for me, except this one, not sure if it's the right aproach tho....

1. my multiple locales are separated in multiple json files (the keys in json must have the same names like in interface OwlDateTimeIntl)

```json
"owl.datetime.component" : {
    "cancelBtnLabel": "Cancel, bye",
    "setBtnLabel": "Set or whatever"
},
```

2. in appmodule constructor, inject the OwlDateTimeIntl and translateService, then subscribe to translateService onLangChange,

```ts
export class AppModule {
    constructor(languageService: LanguageService,
                translateService: TranslateService,
                dateTimeAdapter: DateTimeAdapter<any>,
                owlDateTime: OwlDateTimeIntl) 
    {
        languageService.langChanged$.subscribe(lang => {
                translateService.use(lang);
                dateTimeAdapter.setLocale(lang);
            }
        );
        InjectorService.injector = injector;
        translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
            this.updateOWlDateTime(owlDateTime, translateService);
        });
    }
```

3. then just use translator service to override values in OwlDateTimeIntl (I used the for loop to set all what the json contains)

```ts
private updateOWlDateTime(owlDateTime: OwlDateTimeIntl, translateService: TranslateService) {
    const owlLocalizedValues = translateService.instant('owl.datetime.component');
    for (const key in owlLocalizedValues) {
        owlDateTime[key] = owlLocalizedValues[key];
    }
    owlDateTime.changes.next();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';


 import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
 import { OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    // use french locale
    {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr'},
  ]`enter code here`
})
export class AppModule { }

    enter code here
```